# How can I remove extra gray spacing in a Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Based on the code below which basically shows a `HTML` file in a Shiny app, how can I remove the extra gray space above and below the infographic?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui = fluidPage(
  navbarPage(htmlOutput("infographic"),
  )
)

server <- function(input,output){
  output$infographic <- renderUI({
    tags$iframe(seamless="seamless", 
                src= "Hub_Infographic.html",
                width=1080, 
                height=1024)
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

app output:

[image]

Desired output (shown by opening the HTML file in the browser):

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing it's because you've set the width and height of the image. So if the browser window is greater than that, the extra space if filled with a grey background. Maybe set width/height to 100%?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the viewport height and width, to make it even a nicer fit, consider defining the horizontal height of your navbar as well in vh, then substract that height from the iframe height. You then have a perfect fullscreen navbar+iframe

`tags$iframe(seamless = "seamless", src= "Hub_Infographic.html", style = "width:100vw;height:100vh;")`

Comment: Can you please update your answer with the full code for where you wrote " consider defining the horizontal height of your navbar as well in vh, then substract that height from the iframe height. You then have a perfect fullscreen navbar+iframe".

Comment: I am kinda confused about the `subtract` part of your answer.

Comment: Depends on your situation, not sure if the blue nav bar comes from in your picture. It is not included in your code. Using units in viewpoint should help you enough to play around with it and solve your issue.

Comment: Yes, the blue navbar comes from the HTML file/picture. So, how do you do the subtraction?